# How to Add UICollectionViewCell (xib) to UIView (iOS)

Tags: xib, subview

I have a couple CellChart.swift and CellChart.xib is UICollectionViewCell

Now I don't want use them in CollectionView, i want add this Chart to UIView in ViewController, is it possible?

Thanks!